# Product Collection in custom class always use EAV tables

Tags: magento2

I have a very weird sutuation. My class is as simple as this:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Company\Helper;

class MyHelper
{
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    }

    public function someMethod()
    {
        ...
        $productCollection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect(['attr1','attr2', 'attr3']);
        echo $productCollection->load()->getSelect(); // SELECT `e`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
    }
    ...
}
```

Note how raw collection query looks like: *SELECT `e`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`

I was expecting Magento to use product flat table, since I have **catalog/frontend/flat_catalog_product = 1** in my database.

I tried to debug this, and figured out that this happens because **Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Product\Flat\State** has **$isAvailable = false** as an argument. If I change this to true, by using virtual types magic, as explained here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/139334/26850

```
<virtualType name="enabledFlatState" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Product\Flat\State">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="isAvailable" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<virtualType name="enabledFlatStateProductCollection" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="catalogProductFlatState" xsi:type="object">enabledFlatState</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<virtualType name="enabledFlatStateProductCollectionFactory" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="instanceName" xsi:type="string">enabledFlatStateProductCollection</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<type name="Vendor\Company\Helper\MyHelper">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="productCollectionFactory" xsi:type="object">enabledFlatStateProductCollectionFactory</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

I was able to get the query that I wanted:

*SELECT 1 AS `status`, `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`created_at`, `e`.`updated_at`, `e`.`sku`, `e`.`sku`, `e`.`attr1`, `e`.`attr2`, `e`.`attr3`, `e`.`temando_package_1_height` FROM `catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e`*

But this is not what I want. I know that Magento should **always** use flat table for product collection if it was set like that in configuration.

My question is - what can cause Magento not to follow system configuration (flat tables turned ON)? What can possibly have impact on this?

P.S. I am using Magento 2.1.7.
**P.S.S. Product collection on category pages works just fine, this is only for my custom class!**

Comment: Did you do full reindex of the site?

Comment: Did you get the answer.